# Using form_for with Awesome Nested Set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I have a Comment model with the acts_as_nested_set enabled, but when I try to do something like this (for nested comments), i receive the error "comment_comments_path not found", presumably because the default pathing doesn't work with Awesome Nested Set. How do I get around this?

```
            <%= form_for([@comment, @comment.children.build]) do |f| %>

           <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder=>'What do you think?'%>

           <%= f.submit 'Submit Reply'%>
            <%  end %>
```

I also tried this:

```
            <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>

            <% @comment.children.each do |sub|  %>
            <%= f.fields_for :children, sub do |child| %>

            <%= child.text_area :content, :placeholder=>'What do you think?'%>

           <%= f.submit 'Submit Reply'%>
            <% end  %>
            <% end  %>
            <%  end %>
```

but it didn't generate a textbox for me to type in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, yeah you have to build it first then have fields for, so this:

```
<% @comment.children.build %>

<%= form_for([@comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :children do |child| %>
    <%= child.text_area :content, :placeholder=>'What do you think?'%>
    <% end  %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Reply'%>
  <% end  %>
<% end  %>
```

This will have a form for all existing children + the new one. If you want only a form for a new child then you'll want this instead:

```
<%= form_for([@comment]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for @comment.children.build, :children do |child| %>
    <%= child.text_area :content, :placeholder=>'What do you think?'%>
    <% end  %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit Reply'%>
  <% end  %>
<% end  %>
```